My compilation including latexindent produces lots of .bak files
I'm using arara in vs code with texlive 2023 on windows 10.
I'm using this kind of text line in my document :
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///arara
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes, interaction: batchmode}
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes,synctex: no, interaction: batchmode} if found('log', '(undefined references|Please rerun|Rerun to get)')
% arara: indent: {overwrite: on, silent :yes}

When I compile a lot of files .bak (.bak0;.bak1 ...) are produce? How can I solve this issue

The indent program uses the bak files to create backups before if changes your files. Are you sure you don't want it to create backups in case something goes wrong?

well the problem is not create one bak but there is a lot of them it's like the compilationgo on and on and on

See section 5 of the latexindent user guide how to change the number of backups to one https://texdoc.org/serve/latexindent/0

(or not run latexindent every time you compile)

well , great advice thanks i'm searching for this rule "maxNumberOfBackUps:integer"  in arara ...

You want to change this in your latexindent configuration, not in arara.

it's not possible in the first line of my .tex where i put % arara: indent: {overwrite: on, silent :yes} ?

Place a file called localSettings.yaml, .localSettings.yaml, latexindent.yaml, or .latexindent.yaml in your home directory and add onlyOneBackUp: 1 to this file.

I get this error message: An error occurred while trying to open the ficg=hier c:/users/moi/Appdata/local ....the ararconfig.yaml file cannot be found

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html#backup-and-log-file-preferences

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz perhaps your comment is an answer?

@cmhughes Could you write an answer instead? You know your way around latexindent much better than me!

Create the following file latexindent.yaml
onlyOneBackUp: 1

and call latexindent as follows
latexindent.pl -l myfile.tex

See https://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sec-default-user-local.html#backup-and-log-file-preferences for more details and options.
